# How to connect to open wifi networks using wpa_cli?

Tags: wifi, network-interface, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

I am failing to connect to open wifi networks using wpa_cli. I am trying to connect to the open wifi networks in the following way:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli -i wlp3s0
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "Guest"
> enable_network 0
```

When I try to enable the network sometimes it just replies OK and then nothing. Few times, I have seen it to reply following:

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
```

wpa_cli is working without any issue for password protected networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually to connect to a network requires to use some authentication mechanism. This is handled among other settings by wpa_supplicant's [`key_mgmt` variable](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf?h=hostap_2_9#n893):

> ```
> # key_mgmt: list of accepted authenticated key management protocols
> # WPA-PSK = WPA pre-shared key (this requires 'psk' field)
> # WPA-EAP = WPA using EAP authentication
> # IEEE8021X = IEEE 802.1X using EAP authentication and (optionally) dynamically
> # generated WEP keys
> # NONE = WPA is not used; plaintext or static WEP could be used
> [...]
> # If not set, this defaults to: WPA-PSK WPA-EAP
> ```

Connecting to an *open* SSID means not using any authentication nor cipher: the parameter has to be changed from default to `NONE` as written above (*plaintext* case).

This value can be set dynamically through the `wpa_cli` command before enabling (the use) of the network as many other values:

```
> help set_network
commands:
  set_network <network id> <variable> <value> = set network variables (shows
    list of variables when run without arguments)
```

This command should be inserted before `enable_network`:

```
set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE
```

An example run could look like this:

```
# wpa_cli -i wlp3s0
wpa_cli v2.9
[...]
Interactive mode

> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "Guest"
> set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE
> enable_network 0
OK
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (SSID='Guest' freq=2437 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (SSID='Guest' freq=2437 MHz)
<3>Associated with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 12:34:56:78:9a:bc completed [id=0 id_str=]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
[...]
```

Comment: I was expecting some kind of key management. Didn't know how to do it. help command in the interactive mode or `man wpa_cli` didn't help. Thank you so much. It is working now.